# How to create an import spec for CSVs with varying numbers of fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a macro in Access that runs every time the database is opened. It scans a folder for any new CSV files and if a file doesn't have a table in the database, a linked table is created. I need to specify that the first field is a date, the second field is text (it defaults to numbers since most are values like 00005, 00011, etc.), and that the delimiter is a semicolon, and that the first row contains the field headers.

So far I've only found one main suggestion and that's to create an import spec and use that in the docmd.TransferText. However, because the files I'm importing have a varying number of fields, that doesn't work. I've also seen people suggest that I create an import spec with a number of fields much greater than I would ever need, but when I do that it doesn't import the first row as field names.

```
Function MassImport()

 Dim strPathFile As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim strTableName As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 blnHasFieldNames = True

 strPath = "C:\Users\frank\OneDrive\Desktop\MRapnikas Temp\Database\Data\"

 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")


Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    strTableName = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)

    'If fExistTable(strTableName) = False Then DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, "AutoImportSpecs", strTableName, strPath & strFile, 1
    If fExistTable(strTableName) = False Then DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , strTableName, strPath & strFile, 1

    strFile = Dir()

Loop

End Function
```

Currently the macro imports the CSV correctly and even has the first field as a date, but the second field is a number. If I use the "AutoImportSpecs" specification name then it will only import the number of fields that the specification has.

Comment: So you are setting a link, not importing to a local table? How many links are there? How many do you expect to create? Why is the CSV structure varied? I don't think there is a solution if you link instead of import.

Comment: @June7 There are currently only about 10 links, but it will most likely grow to about 50. The CSV structure is varied because it's measurement data and different parts have different numbers of measurements.